# multicomp package and emmeans package produce different adjust pvalues for Dunnett procedure

Tags: r, multiple-comparisons, lsmeans, multivariate-distribution, dunnett

For Dunnett adjustment, `multicomp` package and `emmeans` package in R give different results. Anyone knows why? Thanks. Please see my example below. You can see the reported adjusted p-values from `multicomp` package and `emmeans` package are different.

````
> library(multcomp)
> library(emmeans)
> library(DescTools)
> 
> ##generate data
> data <- rbind(
+   data.frame(value = rnorm(100, mean = 130, sd = 80), trt = "high"),
+   data.frame(value = rnorm(100, mean = 120, sd = 80), trt = "mid"),
+   data.frame(value = rnorm(100, mean = 112, sd = 80), trt = "low"),
+   data.frame(value = rnorm(100, mean = 100, sd = 89), trt = "control"))
> 
> data$trt <- factor(data$trt, levels = c("control", "high", "mid", "low"))
> 
> ##use multicomp to perform dunnett test 
> model <- aov(value ~ trt, data = data)
> glht_res <- glht(model, linfct = mcp(trt = rbind(c(1, -1, 0, 0), 
+                                                  c(1, 0, -1, 0),
+                                                  c(1, 0, 0, -1))))
> res_Dunnett <- glht(model, linfct = mcp(trt = "Dunnett"))
> summary(res_Dunnett)

     Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses

Multiple Comparisons of Means: Dunnett Contrasts


Fit: aov(formula = value ~ trt, data = data)

Linear Hypotheses:
                    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
high - control == 0   30.580     12.125   2.522   0.0324 *
mid - control == 0     6.616     12.125   0.546   0.9057  
low - control == 0    22.156     12.125   1.827   0.1673  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
(Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)

> ## use emmeans to perform dunnett
> 
> model.emm <- emmeans(model, specs = ~ trt)
> contrast(model.emm, method = list(c(1, -1, 0, 0), 
+                                    c(1, 0, -1, 0),
+                                    c(1, 0, 0, -1)),
+ adjust = "dunnett")
 contrast       estimate   SE  df t.ratio p.value
 c(1, -1, 0, 0)   -30.58 12.1 396  -2.522  0.0334
 c(1, 0, -1, 0)    -6.62 12.1 396  -0.546  0.8755
 c(1, 0, 0, -1)   -22.16 12.1 396  -1.827  0.1718

P value adjustment: dunnettx method for 3 tests 
> 
> ##use destools to perform Dunnett test
> DunnettTest(value ~ trt, data = data, control="control", conf.level=0.05)

  Dunnett's test for comparing several treatments with a control :  
    5% family-wise confidence level

$control
                  diff    lwr.ci   upr.ci   pval    
high-control 30.579714 22.726359 38.43307 0.0324 *  
mid-control   6.615897 -1.237457 14.46925 0.9057    
low-control  22.155691 14.302337 30.00905 0.1673    

---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```
````

Answer (score 9):

I've dug through the source code (the great thing about it being open), and it turns out that `glht(..., mcp(trt = "Dunnett"))` pulls its *P*-values out of a multivariate t distribution. They call `mvtnorm::pmvt` with the observed t statistics and correlation matrix (actual code [here](https://github.com/cran/multcomp/blob/master/R/pqfunctions.R#L33)). `DescTools::DunnettTest` does roughly the same (code [here](https://github.com/cran/DescTools/blob/master/R/Tests.r#L5031)).

`emmeans` does something.. different. Already in the documentation they call their `dunnetx` method "a close approximation to the Dunnett adjustment". This is the [actual source](https://github.com/rvlenth/emmeans/blob/master/R/summary.R#L1243):

```
### My approximate dunnett distribution 
### - a mix of the Tukey cdf and Sidak-corrected t
.pdunnx = function(x, k, df, twt = (k - 1)/k) {
    tukey = ptukey(sqrt(2)*x, (1 + sqrt(1 + 8*k))/2, df)
    sidak = (pf(x^2, 1, df))^k
    twt*tukey + (1 - twt)*sidak
}
```

(`x` are the t statistics, `k` the number of contrasts and `df` self-explanatory)

You can make `emmeans` match the others by using `adjust="mvt"` which will then also call `mvtnorm::pmvt`. Either way I wouldn't sweat the small differences in *P*-values, or I'd worry equally much about  the fact that any default call to `mvtnorm::pmvt` (which wasn't changed in any of the above) targets an absolute epsilon of $1e{-}3$, so your *P*-values would only be accurate to about 3 decimal places anyway.

Small aside, unless you include a seed there will never be a match against any subsequent runs of your randomly sampling code (making your example non-reproducible).

Comment: That is super fast response and super helpful! Agree differences are very small. But I would go with multivariate T since I think that is how Dunnett test was orginally defined. Thanks so much for links to the source code. will check them out. Also, totally agree with the random seed part!

Comment: If you felt PBulls sufficiently answered your question, feel free to accept it by hitting the checkmark next to the answer and upvoting it @user13154