# balanced and unbalanced dose response experiments

Tags: experiment-design, multiple-comparisons, clinical-trials, dose-response, dunnett

Consider a dose response study where there are four active treatments (from the highest dose and lowest dose) and also a control. One goal is to test the hypothesis that treatments are more effective than the control (mostly interested in the higher doses vs control). Another goal is the evaluate the dose response relationship.

Consider two experiments: 1. each of the five groups (the four treatments and the control) get  equal number of subjects, 2 the lowest dose get half of the number subjects assigned to the control and the other three treatment groups.

Compared to experiment 1, experiment 2 will have less power for testing lowest dose vs control comparison but it requires less subjects than experiment 1. What other pros and cons for experiment 2 need to be put into consideration? Bias in the estimation or increase of standard error for testing treatment vs control comparison? Any suggestion?

Also concern, in experiment 2, is dunnett test still valid since we will no longer have equal correlation among the test statistics?

Comment: MCP-Mod (or at least the MCP step in this case) is generally considered fit-for-purpose by regulators for testing dose-response - in short it will depend on the assumed & true dose-response shape. Is this what you're considering? Several (not all!) modern implementations of Dunnett's test draw from the multivariate t directly, addressing your last concern (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/631129/multicomp-package-and-emmeans-package-produce-different-adjust-pvalues-for-dunne/631132#631132)). This includes `DoseFinding::MCTtest`.